# How to have only one person on a webpage, the others go on a waiting screen

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm currently trying to develop my first web application with node.js and Socket.IO.

I need to have only one person on my main page, and when someone wants to connect to the page, the server redirects him to the waiting page where he can click on a button to go back to the man page (obviously when there is nobody on the page).

I'm stuck trying to do it with socket.IO. I thought about "express-session" but don't really know how to implement it.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I think people will want to see whatever code you've written so far in order to try and help you troubleshoot it.

Comment: I decided not to post my code because i'm almost sure I am not getting anywhere with it. I just ask for new solutions i don't know, or examples ppl have in mind ;)